# ASP NET core API timesout while posting huge JSON

Tags: azure, storage

We have created Azure function to load the json file from Azure Blob storage and tried to post the data to an API to insert the data into SQL DB. since the file size is huge the POST API is timed out. I need suggestion for alternative approach to insert the json data to SQL DB quickly

Comment: This is a bit general for Stack Overflow. 
Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Without any more detail than what you've provided, AND *assuming* you control both ends of this API equation... it sounds like you need to

1. write logic that can communicate some sort of transaction on the target API
2. rewrite the Azure func to segment the JSON blob into multiple API calls
3. then communicate to the target that all calls have completed (committing the transaction that you started)

Comment: Is there any other way to post huge data from .net core 2.0 to sql server within very less time.  I assume sqlbulkcopy don't work in core 2.0